# Repeat data in the empty lines untill a non-empty line occurs

Tags: python, awk, formatting

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
 xyz123            2.000    -0.3974     0.0  hij123       
                                          6.0  lmn123      
                                          8.7  efg123      
                                         13.9  uvw123      
                                         28.5  rst123       
 abc123            10.000     0.1943     0.0  wxy123       
                                         10.7  xyz123       
                                         19.9  pqr123     
                                         20.6  stu123      
                                         20.6  klm123      
 def123            50.000    -0.2595    19.2  jkl123      
                                         26.1  stu123      
                                         27.1  def123     
                                         27.1  ghi123     
                                         27.6  abc123
```

***  uvw123            15.000    -0.3635

```
 lmn123            40.000    -0.3695     19.2  jkl123      
                                         26.1  stu123      
                                         27.1  def123     
                                         27.1  ghi123     
                                         27.6  abc123
```

I need to transform it into:

```
xyz123,2.000,-0.3974,0.0,hij123       
xyz123,2.000,-0.3974,6.0,lmn123      
xyz123,2.000,-0.3974,8.7,efg123      
xyz123,2.000,-0.3974,13.9,uvw123      
xyz123,2.000,-0.3974,28.5,rst123       
abc123,10.000,0.1943,0.0,wxy123       
abc123,10.000,0.1943,10.7,xyz123       
abc123,10.000,0.1943,19.9,pqr123     
abc123,10.000,0.1943,20.6,stu123      
abc123,10.000,0.1943,20.6,klm123      
def123,50.000,-0.2595,19.2,jkl123      
def123,50.000,-0.2595,26.1,stu123      
def123,50.000,-0.2595,27.1,def123     
def123,50.000,-0.2595,27.1,ghi123     
def123,50.000,-0.2595,27.6,abc123
```

*** uvw123,15.000,-0.3635,

```
lmn123,40.000,-0.3695,19.2,jkl123      
lmn123,40.000,-0.3695,26.1,stu123      
lmn123,40.000,-0.3695,27.1,def123     
lmn123,40.000,-0.3695,27.1,ghi123     
lmn123,40.000,-0.3695,27.6,abc123
```

How can I do this using Python or AWK or sed?

UPDATE: So if you notice there is a line in the input data which looks like "     uvw123            15.000    -0.3635     " and when I use the python code from aix this line gets messed up. Is there a way to modify your code and correctly output the rows such as the one I showed?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - SO is not a site to get people to write code for you.

Comment: Agreed...but I'm not trying to convince people to write codes for me. I can do that for most parts myself. I'm not a Python expert and thought if someone can help me further. Thanks Lattyware.

Comment: If you can do most of it yourself, then do so, and come back with a specific problem, showing your code.

Comment: It *is* a site where people can learn stuff though. And the answer to questions like this often have stuff to learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this to get started -

```
awk 'NF>3{a=$1;b=$2;c=$3;$1=$1;print;next}NF<3{d=$1;e=$2;print a,b,c,d,e;next}{$1=$1;}1' OFS=',' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python solution:

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as f:
  prev = []
  for line in f:
    tok = [t for t in re.split(r'\s+', line.rstrip()) if t]
    if len(tok) < len(prev):
      tok = prev[:-len(tok)] + tok
    print ','.join(tok)
    prev = tok
```

It keeps track of the most recent value for each column (in `prev`) and uses that to populate the missing columns in the current line.

Comment: Wow!! this is perfect. Thanks for the suggestions and solutions. This is very helpful.

Comment: Hi Aix,I have updated my problem as I ran into an unexpected scenario with the input file. Can you please help me with the code again. Many thanks.

Comment: @Rishi: Please post a separate question, and I am sure someone will help.

Comment: @Rishi -- If this post was helpful to you and (initially) solved your problem, you should accept it as an answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I believe I did accept that as an answer but then I ran into something unexpected and had to modify my question a little bit and that is why I reposted my question with the modified version. My apologies if it created confusions.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} NF == 5 {a = $1; b = $2; c = $3; $1 = $1; print; next} {$4 = $1; $5 = $2; $1 = a; $2 = b; $3 = c; print}' inputfile
```

Broken onto multiple lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        OFS = ","
    } 
    NF == 5 {
        a = $1; 
        b = $2; 
        c = $3; 
        $1 = $1; 
        print; 
        next
    } 
    {
        $4 = $1; 
        $5 = $2; 
        $1 = a; 
        $2 = b; 
        $3 = c; 
        print
    }' inputfile
```

Doing `$1 = $1` forces the line to be reassembled with the new `OFS`.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` (and `tr`) solution, not particularly elegant:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = ","}
  { if (NF == 5) {
    split($0, a); print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
  } else {
    print a[1], a[2], a[3], $1, $2
  } }' | tr -d ' \t'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is tab-delimited.

You can iterate each line, and apply `split("\t")` to each line e.g.

```
for line in lines:
    result = line.split("\t")
```

if len(result) is 5, then you hit a new section. You can unpack the values as such

```
h1, h2, h3, v1, v2 = result
```

otherwise, it is

```
v1, v2 = result
```

You can then print out the variables using `",".join([h1, h2, h3, v1, v2])`.

As for the second problem, without seeing the invisible characters in the file, it is hard to tell. You can see them by using "set list" in vi, for example.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","} /^[^ ]/ {f1=$1; f2=$2; f3=$3; f4=$4; f5=$5} /^[ ]/ {f4=$1; f5=$2}  {print f1,f2,f3,f4,f5}' < input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";} NF==2{print a,b,c,$1,$2}{};NF==5{a=$1; b=$2; c=$3;print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}{}' logfile
```

This first sets the output field separator to a tab (you can change this as needed) and then looks to see how many columns are in the line. If there are 5, it sets the first three equal to variables a,b and c, then prints them all out.

If there are only two columns, it prints a, b and c (i.e. the first three columns of the last full row) followed by the two columns from this line.

**Update:**

I hadn't noticed the line with only three columns! The awk command below should give the output as you specified:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";} $1~/^[a-z]/{a=$1; b=$2; c=$3;print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}{}$1!~/^[a-z]/{print a,b,c,$1,$2}{}' logfile
```

This works similarly to before, but looks if the first field starts with a letter rather than looking at the number of columns. This regex could be made more specific if required.

Comment: Thanks John, I ran your AWK statement and it did a great job but it removed this line "uvw123            15.000    -0.3635   " completely from the output file. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed that line! I've updated my answer now to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi John, your first awk statement worked better. With your new Awk statement the second line of every repeat is incorrect and it also doesn't bring this line "uvw123 15.000 -0.3635 " as a new line. Something is getting messed up...and I'm working to see if I can fix it without bothering you.

Comment: Much better but if you see the output this is what it does: def123,50.000,-0.2595,uvw123,15.000 instead of def123,50.000,-0.2595,27.6,abc123 <newline> uvw123,15.000,-0.3635, ,

Answer (score -1):

a simple grep can do it

```
$ cat so.txt 
xyz123 2.000 -0.3974 0.0 hij123
6.0 lmn123
8.7 efg123
13.9 uvw123
28.5 rst123
abc123 10.000 0.1943 0.0 wxy123
10.7 xyz123
19.9 pqr123
20.6 stu123
20.6 klm123
def123 50.000 -0.2595 19.2 jkl123
26.1 stu123
27.1 def123
27.1 ghi123
27.6 abc123
$ cat so.txt | grep "-"
xyz123 2.000 -0.3974 0.0 hij123
def123 50.000 -0.2595 19.2 jkl123
```

Comment: With due respect @DennisWilliamson, but you could have handled that better :/

Comment: @Dennis, thanks for the suggestion to trim my prompt, that's a good one. And for your information, the question was edited. When I posted this answer, the input in the question was exactly as it appears in the so.txt and the desired output was grep's output. I had no more than 1 minute idle, and I decided to spend it with opening up SO and picking this post and trying to help OP -- with all good faith. So I don't understand, why this hostility?

Comment: Please accept my apologies. However, after having looked at the original form of the question, I disagree that the desired output matches the output of `grep`.